# Can't send the updated value to onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Gridster.js and Twitter Bootstrap.

What I expect to be done is when I double-click on a grid, a modal comes and you can customize your grid. Now I'm only focusing to the delete option.

The issue is that it gives through the id of the current grid to the delete button's click function, but when I delete one and try to delete an other one, as on the console you can see, the ID remains the same that it got before.

How could I solve this issue?

**A part from the source:**

```
$(document).on("dblclick", ".gs_w", function(){

    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    var widgetId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('1: '+widgetId);
    $('#myModalLabel').html('You selected the '+widgetId+'. item.');

    $('#deleteBtn').on('click', function(){
        console.log('x: '+widgetId);
        gridster.remove_widget( $('#'+widgetId) , function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        });
    });

});
```

**Console.log results:**

```
1: 3 
x: 3 
1: 7 
x: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on("dblclick", ".gs_w", function(){

        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
        var widgetId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log('1: '+widgetId);
        $('#myModalLabel').html('You selected the '+widgetId+'. item.');

        $('#deleteBtn').off('click');
        $('#deleteBtn').click(function(){
            console.log('x: '+widgetId);
            gridster.remove_widget( $('#'+widgetId) , function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        });

    });
```